# Generate classes java from a wsdl url - returning error 401

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I am trying to generate Java Classes from WSDL URL, but I am receiving an error 401.
I would like to know if I can configure it to input the username/password.

Obs.: If I download the .wsdl file and use it directly it works, but I would like to make something more automatic.

Here my code:

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

          <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.14.0</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>ca.applications.linte.client.generate</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                  <schema>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/ws-consentement-sollicitation-web/ws/LNTEService.wsdl</url>
                  </schema>
                </schemas>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
                
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by jaxb. Please refer this answer: [Generate a schema for WSDL with HTTP authentication and the maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137202/generate-a-schema-for-wsdl-with-http-authentication-and-the-maven-jaxb2-plugin). You could try using the hack mentioned in this.